# Override base class PostSharp aspect in derived class

Tags: c#, postsharp, aspect

I have a generic repository class with various methods marked with a **PostSharp** aspect (`SecuredOperation`)...

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>, ISecurable
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{      
    ...

    [SecuredOperation(DomainAccess.Write)]        
    public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        this.Context.AddEntity(entity);
    }

    ...
}
```

In some of my derived repository classes I want to change the required access on the `Add()` method (e.g. `DomainAccess.None`).

My initial attempt was to override the method and reapply the aspect...

```
public class SomeRepository : Repository<SomeEntity>
{       
    ...

    [SecuredOperation(DomainAccess.None)]
    public override void Add(SomeEntity entity)
    {
        base.Add(entity);
    }

    ...
}
```

The aspect is correctly applied to this overridden method, however once I call the base class implementation the base class aspect kicks in.

Obviously duplicating the base class logic in the derived classes is not a solution.

**How can I get around this problem of overriding a base class aspect in a derived class?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PostSharp pro but I think you need to add and set the **AttributeReplace** value to true on the overridden method. There is also an AllowMultiple

```
[SecuredOperation(DomainAccess.None, AttributeReplace = true)]
    public override void Add(SomeEntity entity)
```

You can also define the aspect so that it will always override a previous one by adding the following

```
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
```

to the aspect class definition.

PostSharp doc [link](http://doc.postsharp.net/##multicast-override)